# Cannot run libGDX sample project

Tags: android-studio, libgdx, android-studio-3.0

Recently I downloaded libGDX sample project and it is not running due to following error on Android studio.

*Could not find method compile() for arguments [com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.1] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
Please install the Android Support Repository from the Android SDK Manager.*

I downloaded the Android Support Repository but it is still the same.

Android studio version - 3.1.3

[Project link](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx-demo-superjumper)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem with Gradle. How are you building your project? If you have the gradle-plugin in Android Studio (or IntelliJ) you can click a button to sync and build your project.
If you want to build your project on the command line with gradle, you can follow this basic process on the command line:
**clean and build all modules**

```
./gradlew clean
./gradlew build
```

clean and build android and finally test to make sure ;):

```
./gradlew android:clean
./gradlew android:build
./gradlew android:test
```

If I'm wrong please correct me but I believe those are the corret commands...I'm on OSX so if you are building on windows I think the first argument its just .gradlew...